# RAILS How I can forward mail to activate the user account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I am following the tutorial rails Michael Hartl.
I've gotten emails sent to activate the user account but if a user has not gotten the email, can do nothing with your account.
How I can forward the email to activate the user account if the first time it did not come?

I tried adding the following code but with no luck.

sessions_controller.rb:

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      if user.activated?
        log_in user
        params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
        redirect_back_or user
      else
        message  = "Cuenta no activada. "
        message += "Revise su correo electronico para activar la cuenta."
--->    user.send_activation_email
        flash[:warning] = message
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Email y/o Contraseña incorrectos.'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in Hartl's tutorial, the activation digest is only created when the user is created.  In your User model, you should see:

```
before_create :create_activation_digest
```

You need to create a new activation token each time you send an activation email to your users.

One approach is to remove the above line and add this to your `send_activation_email` method:

```
# Sends activation email.
def send_activation_email
  create_activation_digest
  self.save
  UserMailer.account_activation(self).deliver_now
end
```

Note you also need to save the user instance here so that the activation token is saved.

There may be other (and better) approaches, but this should at least get you on track.